# Sum all values in in two linked tables in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

New to PowerBI, I imported a table that has Company Names, Revenue and an internal Rating ( A - F). Currently there are no companies that are rated D.

In my dashboard I would like to sum the revenue up pivoted up the internal rating, however I would also like to show that there is no revenue for rating D. If I do a normal table, there is no rating D so this is ignored.

As a workaround I have created a reference table for all ratings, including D. I am therefore trying to work out how to sum all revenues from the first table by rating, and if no revenue occurs have 0.

This is my current method but wont split the revenue by rating.

```
Workings = SUMX(FILTER(
    'ALL','ALL'[Rating] = 'Reference'[Rating] ),[Revenue])
```

Any help with this method or an idea of any other method would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your original Problem (that D is not shown because it has no value):
On your axis (Y-axis for example) you can change from "Sum" to "Count(Distinct)". That works for me, I hope it helps.